# Why are my faces different colors with the same material on them?

Tags: mesh, light, faces, color, shadows

I don't know why this is happening is it because of the light? Something new with how lights/shadows work in 2.8? This happend on the 2.8 Candidate 1 and 2. I have plane with emission as light in this project. You can clearly see that faces are different. This never happend to me.

This is cube mesh with verteces merged in center to create a blade.

**I tried flipping normals, playing with light and the object but nothing worked.**

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

**EDIT**
After playing with light some more I got to the point on last picute. I just upped the strength of the lights. Didn't really help you can just see it less.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I understand well the question, you're using 'Lookdev' rendering in the first 2 images. This means that light is not constant around as lookdev is based on a HRDI environment texture. Lookdev rendering = second button from the right on the upper right corner of the 3D view.

Comment: In rendered and solid view I get the same problem.

Comment: I will add another render picture.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. There is a section in the tip of the dagger that is ever so slightly brighter. I'd need to see the wireframe to check what causes this.

Comment: Gonna add it now.